# Can I create a component which overrides and to be able to customize mat-error?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angularjs-directive

I have created a compoenent called bl-error which contains mat-error (see code below):

this is the bl-error.component.ts:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {MatError} from '@angular/material/form-field';

@Component({
    selector: 'bl-error',
    templateUrl: './bl-error.component.html',
    styleUrls:["./bl-error.component.scss"]
})
export class BlErrorComponent extends MatError{
    @Input() visible = true;
    @Input() key = 'form.error.required'
    @Input() testLabel = "error_required"
    @Input() formatTranslation = {}
```

}

and this is the bl-error.component.html:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="visible">
    <bl-icon [size]="2" iconClassName="warn"></bl-icon>
    <span [attr.testlabel]="testLabel">{{key | translate : formatTranslation}}</span>
</mat-error>
```

and I use  in the form field of this component bl-text-field:

```
<mat-form-field [appearance]="appearance" 
 [attr.testlabel]="testLabelValue" [hideRequiredMarker]="!label" class="w-100">
<mat-label>{{label | translate}}</mat-label>
<mat-icon *ngIf="displaySearch" matPrefix>search</mat-icon>

<input (keyup)="checkMaxSize()" [formControl]="formControl"
     [maxLength]="maxLength" class="ellipsis"
     [ngClass]="{ 'bl-text-field-uppercase-input': upperCase }"
     [placeholder]="placeholder | translate"
     [readonly]="readOnly"
     [required]="isRequired()"
     autocomplete="off"
     blShowIfTruncated
     id="{{id}}" matInput
     matTooltip="{{formControl.value}}"
     testlabel="input_value"
     [type]="type"
     >
    <bl-button [hidden]="hideSearchAction()" class="cancel-search"
    [size]="1" (click)="onCancel()" [iconButton]="true" [iconClass]="classCross"
      [id]="'btnCancel'" matSuffix></bl-button>
    <mat-hint *ngIf="maxSizeError">
   {{'form.error.libelle.size.too.long'| translate: {'champ':label | translate,'maxLength':maxLength} }}
   </mat-hint>
 <bl-error *ngIf="formControl && formControl.touched && formControl.errors" 
  matTooltipPosition="below"   matTooltipClass="tooltip" 
  [matTooltip]="'form.error.required' | translate" 
  testlabel="error_length" [visible]="formControl.hasError('required')"></bl-error>
 </mat-form-field>
```

but it appears inside the form-field which is not the behavior expected because I want it to be like the mat-error. Please help me and tell me if it is posssible or not.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't wrap `mat-error` inside a component as you lose all its behavior for no benefits:

- `mat-error` already handles the show/hide logic based on the field status (whether it has errors and has been touched)
- When `mat-error` is a direct child of `mat-form-field`, the correct formatting is automatically applied. It doesn't seem to work when it's wrapped inside another component.

To preserve `mat-error` perks, remove it from your component:

```html
<div *ngIf="visible"> <!-- or ng-container if you don't need additional DOM -->
    <bl-icon [size]="2" iconClassName="warn"></bl-icon>
    <span [attr.testlabel]="testLabel">{{key | translate : formatTranslation}}</span>
</div>
```

You can then use your component without styling hacks:

```html
<mat-form-field [appearance]="appearance" [attr.testlabel]="testLabelValue" [hideRequiredMarker]="!label" class="w-100">
  <!-- Skipping declarations -->

  <mat-error>
    <bl-error matTooltipPosition="below" matTooltipClass="tooltip"
     [matTooltip]="'form.error.required' | translate" 
     testlabel="error_length" [visible]="formControl.hasError('required')"></bl-error>
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

NB: you should also apply the `*ngIf` directly from the parent component instead of passing it to the child through the `visible` input

Comment: Thank you and yes you're right and I can add that mat-error is always used inside mat-for-field and it cannot be wrapped in another component inside mat-form-field. But I found another solution I will share it later.